# How to o properly run Pagination with Ajax in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Am trying to implement pagination in ruby on rails.So I reference solution found here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771308/adding-pagination-to-index-html-erb-in-ruby-on-rails-easy-question) by **mmrobins** .

I have tried **will_paginate** options and its working fine.

Now am trying to implement the second options which ajax pagination by following railcasts pagination with ajax. here is the source [link](http://railscasts.com/episodes/174-pagination-with-ajax)

My Issues with Ajax Pagination:

I have configured all the steps as required but when I restart my server,it shows **error undefine local variable or method config for main:Object (NameError)**

I believe this error was caused by setting the following code at **config/environment.rb**

```
config.gem "mislav-will_paginate", :lib => "will_paginate", :source => "http://gems.github.com"
```

any idea on ow to resolve the issue. Am running ruby on rails version

Here is the screenshot of how I save that line of code above at **config/environment.rb**

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your configuration code under 'Rails.application.configure do .. end' in development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do

# your code here
config.gem "mislav-will_paginate", :lib => "will_paginate", :source => "http://gems.github.com"

end
```

Comment: I have done that as you suggested. it paginate but does  not show any pagination button on where to click to load more. between thanks

Comment: Add `<%= will_paginate @collection%>` in your views